# How to set multiple values to one properties in java

Tags: java, maven, spock

I have parametrized Integration tests.
Im curious is it possible to set multiple values to one properties?
something like:

```
mvn -DpropA=valueA -DpropB=valueB -DpropC=valueC
```

but i want:

```
mvn -DpropA=valueA -DpropA=valueB -DpropA=valueC
```

and for  my test to run 3 times with 3 different values

Or maybe someone know better metod for this?

I'm using Spock framework.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass in a string containing valueA, valueB and valueC as such:

```
nvm -DpropA='valueA, valueB, valueC'
```

Then in you main class (or wherever) you could parse out the comma separated values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   for (String arg: args) {
       if (arg.contains(",")) {
           String[] subArgs = arg.split[","];
           // do stuff
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: She wants a different run for each property. I'd suggest adding a profile for each configuration and activate all of them having a test runner plugin for each of them